# JS works in Safari but not IE9 - Can anyone help to make this work?

Tags: javascript

The script I am using can be found at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/qeSZR/1/)

It works in Safari, but not IE9.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html

Comment: Post your code within answer, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event.target.value` where's the `event` variable coming from? Maybe you forgot to specify the parameter?

Try:

```
document.getElementById('filter').onchange = function (event) {
    document.getElementById('field').value = event.target.value  
}
```

Comment: when the user makes the selection from the drop down the id value is suppose to display in the input field. It works in Safari, but does not function at all in IE9.

Comment: I`m sure that's the problem, just add the parameter to the function. - http://jsfiddle.net/qeSZR/3/

Comment: Thanks, the 'event' was the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('filter').onchange = function (event) {
    document.getElementById('field').value = event.target.value  
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you enabled JS in IE9?

If not, then do this in IE9:
1. Click on the "Tools" icon. (Tools icon is on the top right-hand corner of IE9, or Tools can also be found on the Menu bar as "Tools").
2. Then click -> Internet Options" -> Security tab -> Custom Level button -> Scroll to the "Scripting" section near the bottom, and under "Active scripting" select Enable.
3. Click OK.

Now just close down IE9 completely, and restart a new instance of IE9 for javascript to get enabled and start working.

Regards,
Reno Jones